# How to add authorization in Xamarin to my REST Api in Azure with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, xamarin, authorization, azure-active-directory

My question was too broad before. I try focus it to the smaller problem.
I made RestApi on Azure and I made application in Xamarin on mobile. They are working correctly but I would like to create autorization process by Azure Active Directory. I found these links:
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/rest
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c
Could you tell me which approach should I choose? 
Coud you give me any tips for this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: OAuth is used for mobile clients: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth

Comment: Thank you, I will read this document.